# Conflicting implementation on recursive trait

Tags: rust, traits

I am implementing a search algorithm library with two traits: `SearchSpace` and `SearchAlgorithm`.
I want to be able to "spy" some extra info in the search algorithm when running benchmarks, so I created a wrapper for a `SearchSpace`, a `SpiedSearchSpace`, to collect the data.
Finally, I want that any search algorithm that implements `SearchAlgorithm<S>` also implements `SearchAlgorithm<SpiedSearchSpace<S>`
Here is the simplified code:

```rust
trait SearchSpace {}

struct ASearchSpace;
impl SearchSpace for ASearchSpace {}

struct SpiedSearchSpace<S: SearchSpace>(S);
impl<S: SearchSpace> SearchSpace for SpiedSearchSpace<S> {}

trait SearchAlgorithm<S: SearchSpace> {}

// A base implementation for a search algorithm.
struct ASearchAlgorithm<S: SearchSpace>(S);
impl<S: SearchSpace> SearchAlgorithm<S> for ASearchAlgorithm<S> {}

// A recursive implementation, if something implements SearchAlgorithm<S> it should implement SearchAlgorithm<SpiedSearchSpace<S>> too.
impl<S: SearchSpace, A: SearchAlgorithm<S>> SearchAlgorithm<SpiedSearchSpace<S>> for A {}
```

[In the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b9e2145173d2cbf5a2ffd31827168a0a)

But the compiler complains about a conflicting implementation for the trait `SearchAlgorithm`:

```
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `SearchAlgorithm<SpiedSearchSpace<_>>` for type `ASearchAlgorithm<SpiedSearchSpace<_>>`
  --> traits.rs:14:1
   |
12 | impl<S: SearchSpace> SearchAlgorithm<S> for ASearchAlgorithm<S> {}
   | --------------------------------------------------------------- first implementation here
13 |
14 | impl<S: SearchSpace, A: SearchAlgorithm<S>> SearchAlgorithm<SpiedSearchSpace<S>> for A {}
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ conflicting implementation for `ASearchAlgorithm<SpiedSearchSpace<_>>`

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0119`.
```

As I understand this is a recursive trait implementation, given a manual implementation

```
impl SearchAlgorithm<S> for ASearchAlgorithm<S> { ... }
```

`ASearchAlgorithm<S>` would also implement `SearchAlgorithm<SpiedSearchSpace<S>>` and `SearchAlgorithm<SpiedSearchSpace<SpiedSearchSpace<S>>>` and so on.

But I can't see how two conflicting implementations of `SearchAlgorithm<SpiedSearchSpace<S>>` could arise.

Could someone help me understand where and how the conflict arises?

Comment: `SpiedSearchSpace<S>: SearchSpace`, so it is already covered by `S` in the `impl<S: SearchSpace> SearchAlgorithm<S>`.

Comment: Yes, but this means that `ASearchAlgorithm<SpiedSearchSpace<S>>` implements `SearchAlgorithm<SpiedSearch<S>>`, it does not conflict with the implementation of `SearchAlgorithm<SpiedSearch<S>>` for `ASearchAlgorithm<S>` provided by the "recursive" definition, or does it?

Comment: In fact, removing the SearchSpace implementation for SpiedSearchSpace does not eliminate the error ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4ff34be8ed0594d545c9ac5e0da7cf56))

Comment: Unless you are doing something different in the `SearchAlgorithm<SpiedSearchSpace<S>>` impl vs. the `SearchAlgorithm<S>` impl, you do _not_ need the former, as `SpiedSearchSpace<S>` already implements `SearchSpace`, and so is covered by the `SearchAlgorithm<S: SearchSpace>` impl. If you are trying to implement `SearchAlgorithm` differently with a `SpiedSearchSpace`, you cannot do what you want until [specialization](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/31844) is stabilized.

Comment: The code in the playground link suffers the same problem because you have a `impl<S> SearchAlgorithm<S> for ASearchAlgorithm<S>` - `S` covers _all_ types, including `SpiedSearchSpace`s.

Comment: I removed the trait bound in the wrong place. [Here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ad3a3a46a0042ce251ba3725f76f8d79) I removed from the trait declaration and it does compile without errors.

Comment: My intention with the line `impl<S: SearchSpace, A: SearchAlgorithm<S>> SearchAlgorithm<SpiedSearchSpace<S>> for A {}` is not to provide a new specialized implementation of `SearchAlgorithm<SpiedSearchSpace<S>>` for `ASearchAlgorithm<SpiedSearch<S>>` but for any implementor of `SearchAlgorithm<S>` to also implement `SearchAlgorithm<SpiedSearchSpace<S>>` (which are different traits).

Comment: It seems that the fact that `SpiedSearchSpace<S>: SearchSpace` is resulting in a new implementation of `SearchAlgorithm<SpiedSearchSpace<S>>` for `ASearchAlgorithm<SpiedSearchSpace<S>>`, but I'm still failing to see why.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. The generic argument `S` in `impl<S: SearchSpace> SearchAlgorithm<S> for ASearchAlgorithm<S>` spans _all_ types implementing `SearchSpace`. This includes `SpiedSearchSpace<T>` for _all_ `T: SearchSpace` (using a different generic parameter `T` to avoid confusion) due to the `impl<S: SearchSpace> SearchSpace for SpiedSearchSpace<S>`.

Comment: Think of it like this: If you declare `N` types (not including `SpiedSearchSpace`) implementing `SearchSpace`, you will have a `SpiedSearchSpace` type (each implementing `SearchSpace`) for each of those `N` `SearchSpace` types. All in all, you have `2N` types implementing `SearchSpace`, including all `N` `SpiedSearchSpace` types. The generic `impl<S: SearchSpace> SearchAlgorithm<S> for ASearchAlgorithm<S>` covers _all_ of the `2N` `SearchSpace` implementing types, including all `SpiedSearchSpace`s.